# perl /python/bash script to get values from files and group them

Tags: python, bash, perl

I have a requirement to process values from different files. I have 5 dirs input,success,manual,retry,current. Each dir has multiple `*.txt` files. Each `.txt` file has `hostname=<hostname>`. I would want to know for each hostname how many files are in input,success,retry,current and manual dir.

For eg.

```
input
    -> A.txt  (HOSTNAME=host1)
    -> B.txt  (HOSTNAME=host2)
    -> C.txt  (HOSTNAME=host3)
    -> D.txt  (HOSTNAME=host1)

success
    -> P.txt (HOSTNAME=host1)
    -> Q.txt (HOSTNAME=host2)
    -> R.txt (HOSTNAME=host1)

OUTPUT
Host   | Input | Success | Current | Retry | Manual
host1  | 2     | 2       |  0      | 0     | 0
host2  | 1     | 1       |  0      | 0     | 0
host3  | 1     |0        |  0      | 0     | 0
```

Would like to know if there are any libraries in perl, python or bash to do this.

Comment: Do you have tried anything to workout on this?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: bash-3.2$ cat ./input/* | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
HOSTNAME=host1 2
HOSTNAME=host3 1
HOSTNAME=host2 1

bash-3.2$ cat ./success/* | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
HOSTNAME=host1 2
HOSTNAME=host2 1

Comment: i got the counts for individual dirs.. but need the total across all dir like the output mentioned above. Also read perl and python has better ways to do it. So will appreciate any pointers

Comment: You're misunderstanding how Stack Overflow works. We're here to help people get code working, not to do your job for you. Write some code and spend a day or two debugging it, and if you think you're completely stuck then post it here and ask for help. It doesn't go down too well here if you just say what you need and expect a solution to come out of the internet. What's more, if you never try to solve your own problems then you aren't gaining any skills, and you won't get very far in software engineering if you're forever asking for favours to get your code written. Try something, and learn.

Comment: I am not expecting a ready made code/solution. As im not an expert in bash/perl/python, i just wanted to know if there any any lib or built in functions that solves the requirement. I got file level result using cat ./input/* | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'  which returns the total count for each hostname in the input dir. I wanted to know if there is a way to get across all dirs. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you either write a proper bash script or, better yet, step up to a full-on scripting language.

Here's an algorithm that will work:

1. for each directory in your list:

   1. get a list of `*.txt` files
   2. open each file
   3. read each line of the file looking for a match

      1. On matched files, increment a two-level hash/dict/object/map/associative array (or whatever your language of choice calls them) keyed by host and directory.  Record the hostname found in a list.
2. remove duplicates from the list of hostnames
3. sort the list of hostnames
4. Use the list of hostnames, the list of directories and the hash of host counts to print a table.

Here's [a link to Perl's built in functions organized by category](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Perl-Functions-by-Category).  The stuff on working with regular expressions, files and directories is particularly relevant.